# Is this how I indicate that only my MX IP is authorized to send email for this domain?

Tags: email, dns, spf

I would have a TXT record as such:

```
v=spf1 mx -all
```

which translates as "only my MX IP is authorized to send email for this domain"?

NOTE: I don't want A records to be able to do so, since my web host is the A record IP address owner.  And there aren't any other servers that should be authorized for my domain, so...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way to specify only servers in your domain MX records are allowed to send mail. All others should be rejected.

As in [this SPF](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax) guide, `mx` means:

> All the A records for all the MX records for domain are tested in
>   order of MX priority. If the client IP is found among them, this
>   mechanism matches.

There are tools online to help you build an SPF record, such as this one from MX Toolbox: https://mxtoolbox.com/SPFRecordGenerator.aspx